# Using multiple UDF functions in Application.Evaluate

Tags: excel, excel-dna

I've built `Excel-Dna Addin` in C#. I have couple of UDF functions that I need to run in some cases.
My cells contains the UDFs with different parameters, I am showing here the simplified version.

I am using `Application.Evaluate` function for this.

My UDF:

```
[ExcelFunction(Name = "Test.TestMe", Description = "Some test", IsHidden = false)]
public static int TestMe(int i)
{
    return i + 1;
}
```

If I call `Application.Evaluate("=Test.TestMe(1)")` I get the result 2.

If I try following: `Application.Evaluate("=Test.TestMe(1)+Test.TestMe(2)")` none of my UDF functions are not called.

The Evaluate function returns: `-2146826259 = #Name?`

I've tried following:

1. Removed `=` before function name `"Test.TestMe(1)+Test.TestMe(2)"`
2. Called with fully qualified name. `"myexcel.xlsx!Test.TestMe(1)+Test.TestMe(2)"`
3. I am aware that `Application.Evaluate` is limited to 255 chars.

I would like to avoid parsing the formula and calling my UDFs one by one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charles Williams (https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/) points to a (now-missing) KB article when he describes this limitation:

> If the string formula contains a reference to both a UDF and a name it
>   will fail with an error 2029 if the name reference occurs AFTER the
>   UDF reference:
>
> - If `fred` is a named range and `xyz()` is a user defined
>     VBA function then this statement returns error 2029 *[i.e. `#NAME?`]*: `Application.Evaluate("=xyz(b1)+fred")`
> - This statement returns the correct value: `Application.Evaluate("=fred+xyz(b1)")`
> - Microsoft KB article 823604 *[which I couldn't find]* identifies this problem but does not correctly diagnose the circumstances that cause it.

Since your UDF name is also a 'name' in Excel, it is presumably subject to the same quirk, giving you this `#NAME?` error.

So I think you're running into a long-standing Excel quirk, and you might want to report this to Microsoft with the *File -> Feedback -> 'Send a Frown'* button.